# Problem with C code, to change a flag on the Last Sunday in October for daylight saving

Tags: c

I have found some code on this site, which I have adjusted to work in the UK for daylight saving time. The plan is to run it once per hour and set a flag accordingly which then adds an hour or leaves as is, to the displayed time. The system time will always be GMT/UTC

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Year=2019;
int Month=10;
int Date=28;
int Dow=0;
char Hours=12;
char Mins=34;
char Seconds=0;
char DST=0;
const char * DAY[]={"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};

int dayofweek(int d, int m, int y) 
{ 
static int t[] = { 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4 }; 
y -= m < 3; 
return ( y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + t[m-1] + d) % 7;
} 

int main()
{

Dow=0;
printf("dst check\n\n");
for(Date=1;Date<=31;Date++)
{

 Dow=dayofweek(Date, Month, Year);

 if ((Month  >  3 && Month < 10 ) || 
  (Month ==  3 && Date >=25 && Dow >= 6 && Dow == 0 && Hours >= 1) ||  // DST starts last Sunday of March;  1am
  (Month == 10 && Date <=25 && Dow <=6 && Dow >= 0) ||
  (Month == 10 && Date <=25 && Dow <=6 && Dow ==0 && Hours < 2)) {   // DST ends last Sunday of November; 2am
DST++;

 }
printf("Date %d:%d:%d",Date,Month,Year);
printf(" %s",DAY[Dow]);
printf(" GMT+%d\n",DST);
DST=0;
}
    return 0;
}
```

This is output generated from the code from October this year, it should detect the the last Sunday in October and change back to GMT/UTC, it seems to be ignoring the Day of week. The last Sunday can only occur between the 25th and 31st of the month. My code just seems to pick up the 25th. The code should change the dst flag on the 27th, which is the last Sunday in October.

I am running this code on an embedded processor, so I don't want to use the time.h library.  The time and date variables will be updated by existing code.

Output from my code.

> dst check
>
> Date 1:10:2019 Tuesday GMT+1
>
> Date 2:10:2019 Wednesday GMT+1
>
> Date 3:10:2019 Thursday GMT+1
>
> Date 4:10:2019 Friday GMT+1
>
> Date 5:10:2019 Saturday GMT+1
>
> Date 6:10:2019 Sunday GMT+1
>
> Date 7:10:2019 Monday GMT+1
>
> Date 8:10:2019 Tuesday GMT+1
>
> Date 9:10:2019 Wednesday GMT+1
>
> Date 10:10:2019 Thursday GMT+1
>
> Date 11:10:2019 Friday GMT+1
>
> Date 12:10:2019 Saturday GMT+1
>
> Date 13:10:2019 Sunday GMT+1
>
> Date 14:10:2019 Monday GMT+1
>
> Date 15:10:2019 Tuesday GMT+1
>
> Date 16:10:2019 Wednesday GMT+1
>
> Date 17:10:2019 Thursday GMT+1
>
> Date 18:10:2019 Friday GMT+1
>
> Date 19:10:2019 Saturday GMT+1
>
> Date 20:10:2019 Sunday GMT+1
>
> Date 21:10:2019 Monday GMT+1
>
> Date 22:10:2019 Tuesday GMT+1
>
> Date 23:10:2019 Wednesday GMT+1
>
> Date 24:10:2019 Thursday GMT+1
>
> Date 25:10:2019 Friday GMT+1
>
> Date 26:10:2019 Saturday GMT+0
>
> Date 27:10:2019 Sunday GMT+0
>
> Date 28:10:2019 Monday GMT+0
>
> Date 29:10:2019 Tuesday GMT+0
>
> Date 30:10:2019 Wednesday GMT+0
>
> Date 31:10:2019 Thursday GMT+0

Comment: Note that the 4th OR condition will never be tested when `Dow` is 0 because then the condition before it will also be true: exchange the two.

Comment: `Dow >= 6 && Dow == 0` can never be true.

Comment: Lightness races in Orbit, this is just an example code that I can play with, this will be inserted into existing working code, that uses and Rtc chip and GPS receiver running on a pic 24 processor, this already updates all the relevant variables in realtime. Once an hour I will trigger a function to Check for dst and update accordingly. I have limited memory and  the code is not finished yet, so, can't use bloated libraries.

Comment: FWIW, when I worked on devices like that, we output every timestamp as UTC (or even GPS time). There wasn't a need for all this additional complexity. Are you sure that you need it?

Comment: I'm concerned that you're hardcoding so much. DST rules are not set in stone for all time. You're potentially giving your code a very short shelflife, which is especially risky when you are pushing to an embedded device, possibly with a limited flash lifetime, and possibly with difficult or no comms. Timezones are handled better with higher-level abstractions over the concept of "date and time", usually with a library (not all libraries are "bloated") - but again I suggest you consider just emitting UTC if you can't keep this up-to-date with e.g. tzdb.

Comment: This project will eventually be a weather station that will display, temperature,  pressure, humidity, sunrise and sunset aswell as moonrise and set. The time autosets from a GPS receiver and uses long and lat to calculate sunrise and set etc, most of this works so far,  having trouble with moonrise and set, I also need to add a touch screen Display. So would be really good to display the correct time.

Comment: I am a newbie to c, I have managed to get this far by finding code on the Internet and adpating it. I don't understand every line of code, espicially in some of the libraries, I have not actually manged to find/adapt some code for dst in the UK that actually works correctly.

Comment: I will have an option to disable dst saving , if the UK govement ever scrap it. This  is a one off home build project, to learn about coding In c, pcb and hardware design.

Comment: Coding time related things is a major pain in the ass and a source of continuous issues.  This is one of those areas that I would always defer to a professional, packaged lib if at all possible and let them deal with DST, new emperor in Japan, leap seconds, political climate changes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the question of OP as puzzle.

To make it easier, I used a `switch` to isolate the special cases of March and October.

The other trick is that the date of last Sunday in month can be easily determined by subtracting the `dayofweek()` of last day in month from date of last day in month.

For the interesting months March and October, the date is 31.

So this is, what I got:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *const day[] = {
  "Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"
};

int dayofweek(int d, int m, int y) 
{ 
  static int t[] = { 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4 }; 
  y -= m < 3; 
  return ( y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + t[m-1] + d) % 7;
} 

int dst(int d, int m, int y, int h)
{
  switch (m) {
    case 3: { // special case March
      // get date of last Sunday in March
      int dls = 31 - dayofweek(31, 3, y);
      return d != dls ? d > dls : h >= 1;
    }
    case 10: { // special case October
      // get date of last Sunday in October
      int dls = 31 - dayofweek(31, 10, y);
      return d != dls ? d < dls : h < 2;
    }
    default:
      return m > 3 && m < 10;
  }
}

void printDateDST(int d, int m, int y, int h)
{
  printf("Date: %2d.%2d.%4d (%s) %2d:00:00 DST %d\n",
    d, m, y, day[dayofweek(d, m, y)], h, dst(d, m, y, h));
}

int main()
{
  // check dst
  // some trivial cases
  for (int m = 1; m <= 12; ++m) printDateDST(10, m, 2019, 9);
  putchar('\n');
  // find edge cases
  int d3 = 0;
  for (int d = 24; d <= 31; ++d) {
    printDateDST(d, 3, 2019, 9);
    if (!d3 && dst(d, 3, 2019, 9)) d3 = d;
  }
  putchar('\n');
  int d10 = 0;
  for (int d = 24; d <= 31; ++d) {
    printDateDST(d, 10, 2019, 9);
    if (!d10 && !dst(d, 10, 2019, 9)) d10 = d;
  }
  putchar('\n');
  // on the edge
  for (int h = 0; h <= 3; ++h) printDateDST(d3, 3, 2019, h);
  putchar('\n');
  for (int h = 0; h <= 3; ++h) printDateDST(d10, 10, 2019, h);
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Date: 10. 1.2019 (Th)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 10. 2.2019 (Su)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 10. 3.2019 (Su)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 10. 4.2019 (We)  9:00:00 DST 1
Date: 10. 5.2019 (Fr)  9:00:00 DST 1
Date: 10. 6.2019 (Mo)  9:00:00 DST 1
Date: 10. 7.2019 (We)  9:00:00 DST 1
Date: 10. 8.2019 (Sa)  9:00:00 DST 1
Date: 10. 9.2019 (Tu)  9:00:00 DST 1
Date: 10.10.2019 (Th)  9:00:00 DST 1
Date: 10.11.2019 (Su)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 10.12.2019 (Tu)  9:00:00 DST 0

Date: 24. 3.2019 (Su)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 25. 3.2019 (Mo)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 26. 3.2019 (Tu)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 27. 3.2019 (We)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 28. 3.2019 (Th)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 29. 3.2019 (Fr)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 30. 3.2019 (Sa)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 31. 3.2019 (Su)  9:00:00 DST 1

Date: 24.10.2019 (Th)  9:00:00 DST 1
Date: 25.10.2019 (Fr)  9:00:00 DST 1
Date: 26.10.2019 (Sa)  9:00:00 DST 1
Date: 27.10.2019 (Su)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 28.10.2019 (Mo)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 29.10.2019 (Tu)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 30.10.2019 (We)  9:00:00 DST 0
Date: 31.10.2019 (Th)  9:00:00 DST 0

Date: 31. 3.2019 (Su)  0:00:00 DST 0
Date: 31. 3.2019 (Su)  1:00:00 DST 1
Date: 31. 3.2019 (Su)  2:00:00 DST 1
Date: 31. 3.2019 (Su)  3:00:00 DST 1

Date: 27.10.2019 (Su)  0:00:00 DST 1
Date: 27.10.2019 (Su)  1:00:00 DST 1
Date: 27.10.2019 (Su)  2:00:00 DST 0
Date: 27.10.2019 (Su)  3:00:00 DST 0
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e15ed8bc6282ea65)

The computations are done according to the facts given in OPs question. I didn't check whether this actually matches the precise DST determination for any location.

Comment: Thanks for the code, works a treat, just need to add into my existing code.